# Triangle Side Sum Program

Tags: python, math, python-2.7

So in math class we had this problem:

You are given a triangle with sides 4 units long. Inside the triangle, there are smaller triangles made from the midsegments of the larger triangles. There are 8 total inscribed triangles. What are the total side lengths?

So, I decided to see if I could write a python program that could solve this for all number of triangles and all side lengths.

Here it is:

```
tri = int(raw_input("How many triangles are there?\n>"))
size = int(raw_input("What is the side length of the biggest triangle?\n>"))
tot = 0
for i in range(1, tri):
    tot += 3*(float(size/i))
print str(tot)
```

I tried it with tri = 8 and size = 4, as in the original problem, and got `24.0`. [As wolfram alpha shows us, that is wrong](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3%2a%284%2B2%2B1%2B1%2F2%2B1%2F4%2B1%2F8%2B1%2F16%2B1%2F32%29).

To try to clarify what happened in each step, I edited it to:

```
tri = int(raw_input("How many triangles are there?\n>"))
size = int(raw_input("What is the side length of the biggest triangle?\n>"))
tot = 0
for i in range(1, tri):
    tot += 3*(float(size/i+0.0000001))
    print str(tot)
print str(tot)
```

The output was:

```
12.0000003
18.0000006
21.0000009
24.0000012
24.0000015
24.0000018
24.0000021
24.0000021
```

Anyone think they know where I went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not looping `tri` times:

```
for i in range(1, tri):
```

The end value is *not* included, so you are counting `1` through to `7` here, not `8`. Remove the `1` and add `1` in the loop:

```
for i in range(tri):
    tot += 3.0 * size / (i + 1)
```

You just need one float value in the calculation, turning `3` into `3.0` does this for us. Unfortunately, in Python 2, `/` will use *integer* or *floor* division when both values are integers, a problem remedied in Python 3:

```
>>> 1 / 2
0
>>> 1.0 / 2
0.5
```

Using `3.0` in the multiplication will make sure the left-hand operand of the division is a float.

You can also use `from __future__ import division` at the top of your script to switch to proper true division for the `/` operator where it always returns a float result.

Next, you are not using proper *exponents* in your formula; it is not `size / (i + 1)`; it is `size / (2 ** i)`; you need to divide by the powers of 2 here; not divide by 1, 2, 3, 4, but 1, 2, 4, 8, etc:

```
tot = 0
for i in range(tri):
    tot += 3.0 * size / 2 ** i
```

Now you get a result that matches Wolfram Alpha:

```
>>> tri, size = 8, 4
>>> tot = 0
>>> for i in range(tri):
...     tot += 3.0 * size / 2 ** i
... 
>>> tot
23.90625
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
float(size/i)
```

to:

```
float(size)/i
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to the [operator precedence in Python](http://www.ibiblio.org/swaroopch/byteofpython/read/operator-precedence.html);

```
size/i+0.0000001
```

uses integer division

```
size/i
```

*then* adds 0.0000001. Effectively, it's

```
(size/i)+0.0000001
```

Instead, use:

```
float(size)/i
```

to force floating point division.